# Using UnivariateSpline generates an error. ValueError: x must be increasing if s > 0

Tags: data-science, curve-fitting, spline, minimum, data-fitting

I want to fit some data to obtain the minimum (both x and y), but when I use UnivariateSpline it will generate an error: 'ValueError: x must be increasing if s > 0'

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd



list_dist=pd.read_csv('C:/.../dist.txt')
dist=list_dist['Distanze']
ar_dist=np.array(dist)



list_energy=pd.read_csv('C:/.../energy.txt')
energy=list_energy['Energie']
ar_energy=np.array(energy)

x = ar_dist
y = ar_energy
print(x)
print(y)

s = UnivariateSpline(x, y)

xs = np.linspace(0, 10, 10000)

ys = s(xs)

ys_min=np.min(ys)
ys_min_pos=np.argmin(ys)
xs_min=xs[ys_min_pos]
print('UnivariateSpline: ', '\n', 'dist_min: ',xs_min , '\t', 'en_min: ', '\t',ys_min)

plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.plot(xs, ys)
plt.show()
```